# combine two group by queries to one to get count of both table's record in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have two queries to get Tutor and Parent Counts by Locations, are below:

```
Select a.LocationId, COUNT(*)  from TutorAddress ta 
inner join Address a on a.Id=ta.AddressId group by a.LocationId
```

Out Put is:

```
LocationId  Count
1            4
14           13
```

second query is:

```
Select a.LocationId, COUNT(*)  from ParentAddress pa 
inner join Address a on a.Id=pa.AddressId group by a.LocationId
```

Out Put is:

```
LocationId  Count
1            6
14           3
12           8
```

I want to merge these two queries and get the result single output as below:

```
LocationId  tutorCount  ParentCount
1              4           6
14            13           3
12            0            8
```

is it possible, i m not able to get how i can achieve this. please help.

Comment: @downvoters, please comment why down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine both query using a left join

```
select a.locationid,
       count(pa.AddressId) as parentcount, COUNT(ta.AddressId) tutorcount
from Address a 
     left join ParentAddress pa on a.Id=pa.AddressId
     left join TutorAddress ta on a.Id=ta.AddressId
group by a.locationid
```